# Re-sizing Image

Tags: html, css

Currently the image slideshow is covering the entire screen. I want the image to only cover 50% of the screen, and I want the image to be centered, vertically and horizontally. Also, I would like to hyperlink the images, so that when the user clicks on the image, the image will appear in a new tab.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
        body {
        font-family: Arial;
        margin: 0;
        }
        * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        img {
        vertical-align: middle;
        }
        /* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
        .container {
        position: relative;
        }
        /* Hide the images by default */
        .mySlides {
        display: none;
        }
        /* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
        .cursor {
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        /* Next & previous buttons */
        .prev,
        .next {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        width: auto;
        padding: 16px;
        margin-top: -50px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20px;
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        }
        /* Position the "next button" to the right */
        .next {
        right: 0;
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
        }
        /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
        .prev:hover,
        .next:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }
        /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
        .numbertext {
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 8px 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        }
        .active,
        .demo:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 6</div>
            <img src="001.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 6</div>
            <img src="002.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 6</div>
            <img src="003.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">4 / 6</div>
            <img src="004.jpg style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">5 / 6</div>
            <img src="005.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
            <div class="numbertext">6 / 6</div>
            <img src="006.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>
        <script>
            var slideIndex = 1;
            showSlides(slideIndex);
            
            function plusSlides(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex += n);
            }
            
            function currentSlide(n) {
              showSlides(slideIndex = n);
            }
            
            function showSlides(n) {
              var i;
              var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
              var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
              var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
              if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
              if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                  slides[i].style.display = "none";
              }
              for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
              }
              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
              dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
              captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can help you with these points : image to only cover 50% of the screen, image to be centered, vertically and horizontally and hyperlink the images, so that when the user clicks on the image, the image will appear in a new tab. Before that I request you to correct the code you have posted, as I can't see any slideshow from your code. Better use absolute links like "http://www.yourdomain.com/image.png" for images, so that we can see images in demo. You can edit code here in this codepen: https://codepen.io/ArunK_UI/pen/QzmOQY

Comment: I use Flexbox to center elements both horizontally and vertically. flexbox is easy to learn and simple to use. worth give a try.